# I am looking for a visualization tool that takes Graphml as input.

Tags: visualization, graphml

Tool I am looking for should support as many features such as multi-relational graphs, more than one edge between given two nodes, nested graphs, hyper-graphs and port feature of Graphml. What are the options? The tools I saw did not seem to support advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

A great tool to visualize GraphML files is [Gephi](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki).

It supports:

- GEXF
- GDF
- GML
- GraphML
- Pajek NET
- GraphViz DOT
- CSV
- UCINET DL
- Tulip TPL
- Netdraw VNA
- Spreadsheet

All features included can be found on [their homepage](https://gephi.org/features/).